# Save robot trajectory as a single figure/image

Tags: ros2, rviz, moveit, trajectory

I would like to show the path planned by moveit2 as a figure in a paper I'm writing. I've seen figures with multiple semi-transparent manipulator arms showing various stages of a certain trajectory, (kind of like a flipbook) before. How do I go about generating such an representation of my trajectory?

[This](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.researchgate.net%2Fpublication%2F342498175%2Ffigure%2Ffig3%2FAS%3A907037701599233%401593266048086%2FRobotic-arm-correctly-moving-along-a-generic-trajectory-from-a-point-A-to-a-point-B.png&tbnid=XOdLMOYM5XEVqM&vet=12ahUKEwi5koim6PiAAxUjmycCHTilAzkQMygHegQIARBp..i&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.researchgate.net%2Ffigure%2FRobotic-arm-correctly-moving-along-a-generic-trajectory-from-a-point-A-to-a-point-B_fig3_342498175&docid=QKxITTFAYxxbvM&w=524&h=441&itg=1&q=robot%20arm%20trajectory&ved=2ahUKEwi5koim6PiAAxUjmycCHTilAzkQMygHegQIARBp) is the look I'm going for, though 3D and with a model of a FE Panda arm.

[This](https://www.smashingrobotics.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/432wef22s.png) representation would also be acceptable if its easier to generate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can something like this be what you are looking for?

[image]

This picture is from MoveIt basic tutorial: https://moveit.picknik.ai/humble/doc/tutorials/quickstart_in_rviz/quickstart_in_rviz_tutorial.html

As you can see, you can set Robot Alpha value, as well as trail step size to a value that is acceptable for you. You can also add a "Trajectory" item in RViz

Comment: this looks exactly like what I'm looking for! I'll have to test it out, but I think a screenshot of this would be perfect!